# Accurate movement with geometry nodes

Tags: animation, geometry-nodes

I need to move a foot using Geometry Nodes.
Instead of using math functions like sine, I would like to be able to control the movement in a more accurate way.

[image: Movement sequence]

I would like to control the y position, z position and x rotation of the foot for each frame.

[image]

The geometry nodes that show the body, the foot and the leg.

Any idea how to do it?

Thanks for your help :)

[image]

Comment: Hello ! I believe this is an occurence of coming full circle here. I don't think GN was built for this level of precision regarding animation tools, at least it's not there yet. Have you tried using the regular animation system ? Armature, rigging, keyframes ?

Comment: Thanks for your reply Gorgeous.
I wanted to use the Geometry Nodes to try to automate the task.
Now I was trying to do it using the GN 'Float Curve'...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I find how to do it.
You must use a  GN 'Float curve' for each kind of movement.

One for the 'X' rotation, another for the 'Z' movement and finally one for the 'Y' movement.

And it works !

[image]

The GN with the 3 'Float curve'
[image]

I leave the file in case it can be of help to someone.

[image]